# Can I remove a method from a class instance in java?

Tags: java, methods, reflection

Lets say I have a class called 'Foo', with some methods:

```
 public class Foo{
    public void a(){
       //stuff
    }

    public void b(){
       //stuff
    }
 }
```

And i have an instance of Foo:
`Foo instanceOfFoo = new Foo();`

Can i remove the method 'a' from 'instanceOfFoo'?

Comment: could you please rephrase your question? nothing will happen if you delete the function declaration assuming it's with 0 references

Comment: What do you mean by remove? What should happen if someone calls that method on that instance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question clearly makes no sence.

Comment: This seems like an XY question. What are you trying to achieve with this approach? As the answers pointed out this is not possible without modifying the bytecode at runtime. Perhaps you can accomplish your goal with a less complicated approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove a method, not without changing the byte code and breaking the code's "contract", but you could extend the class and have the child class's method override throw an [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) if called. Also the child class should deprecate the method, and explain in its javadoc the rationale behind it, and what to use in its place.

This would *change* the class's contract, but in a more responsible way then say fiddling with the byte code.

For example:

```
public class Foo {
    public void a() {
        // stuff
    }

    public void b() {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

```
public class FooChild extends Foo {
    /**
     * @deprecated: This method should no longer be used and will throw an exception
     */
    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void a() {
        String text = "The method a is no longer supported";
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, not really.

Long answer: If you can control the `ClassLoader` being used to load the `Foo` class, you can intercept the request to load the Foo class and use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) or [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) to modify the class's bytecode before loading it.